# jQuery validation plugin

Tags: .net, javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jQuery [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) to validate my form on client side. I am adding a new method using [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) function for every HTML control which have regex (custom) attribute. My HTML control would look like.

```
<input type="text" id="txtInf" name="txtInf" regex="some regular exp" error="check your inf"></input>

$("*[regex]").each(function () {
                  var controlId = $(this).attr('name');    
                  var regex = new RegExp((this).attr('regex'));    
                  var error = $(this).attr('error');    

            $.validator.addMethod(controlId, function (value, element) {

                return this.optional(element) || false;

            }, error);

            $(this).rules("add", { '" + controlId + "': "^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$" }); 

            $(this).validate();
        });
```

Here I am giving method name as **controlId** which is **txtInf**. In below line, I need to give txtInf, but I want to use controlId variable instead, as I want to make this function a generic one. But if I write controlId directly, it searches for the method with the same. But added method is txtInf actually. So I need some way to generalise this line by using controlId variable.

```
$(this).rules("add", {txtInf: "^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$" });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't use a variable name for referencing in an object literal.  What I've done in the past when I need to do something like this is to manually create the JSON string and pass it through parseJSON.  this would look something like:

```
$(this).rules("add", $.parseJSON('{"' + controlId + '":"^[a-zA-Z\'.\s]{1,40}$" }');
```